# Windows Embedded Posready 2009 set hostname from command line

Tags: batch-file, cmd, hostname, windows-embedded

I am searching for a way to change hostname on computer with Windows Embedded Posready 2009 operating system.

Commands `wmic` or `netdom` are not available there.

Google doesn't return anything satisfying.

Is there any other way to change hostname from cmd/batch without installing any additional software?

If there are any more information needed, I will provide them.

Comment: Is Windows Scripting Host available?  VBS/JScript

Comment: Yes, it is available. I will ensure if I can use WSH.
Will it be any difficulty with passing an argument from user to that kind of script?

Comment: With VBS you can use `SENDKEYS` to type the keystrokes into the gui.  It's a bit of a hack but it should work if the applet can be controlled by the keyboard.  An input box can be used to get user input.  If that suits you then google for sendkeys and open another question to get a VBS script.